# What's the appropriate verb for the following context? (найти Vs. находить)

Tags: выбор-слова, вид

I just want to say "I need to **find** it", or "The main thins is that you will find it" (for example, the key, the document, etc.). Now I am not sure which verb is more appropriate to the context that I showed. Google translate showed me both choices for the word find: найти & находить.

> Мне нужно это **найти**.

Vs.

> Мне нужно это **находить**.

Comment: Related: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15108/

Answer (score 5):

When the verb is transitive you have to use a perfective form in positive sentences, like in

*Мне нужно это найти.*

As suggested by **Баян Купи-ка** in the comments imperfective form is also valid here when you talk about some stretched in time duty:

*Мне нужно находить решения, приемлемые для всех* - I [always] have to look for solutions, suitable for everyone.

In negative sentences you use imperfective verbs:

*Мне не нужно этого находить [, чтобы принять правильное решение].*

When the verb is intransitive you can use both perfective and imperfective forms in positive sentences:

*Мне нужно идти. Мне нужно уйти.* - I have to go (leave).

In negative sentences you use imprefective verbs:

*Мне не нужно уходить*.

Notice that perfective/imperfective aspect is often connected with "transitiveness", so sometimes you have only one option.

Comment: generally seems to be the rule of thumb but there's also context dependency, and with transitives in positive statements imperfective aspect is also valid, eg. ***Мне нужно сдавать/сдать зачёт, мне его нужно сдавать/сдать завтра***, some verbs seem to respond better to one aspect than the other, like the said ***найти/находить***

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, you're right. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find it once, `мне нужно это найти`. Example: you lost your glasses and need to find them as soon as possible.

If you need to find it time after time, `мне нужно это находить`.  Example: you have a pet who takes things and hides them in different places in your home.  You need to find the lost thing each time it happens.